# textbox accept only digits

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress


    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789$,"

    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True




    End If
End Sub
```

this code accept only digits and its working like a charm but if i typed a wrong number its not allowing me to use the delete or the backspace on the keyboard how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes back a long time, back when terminals were still used.  You'll also have to allow the backspace character.  Put this in the front of your code:

```
If e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then Exit Sub
```

The Delete key doesn't need any help, that already works.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at

[Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)

> **Keys.Back** : The BACKSPACE key.