# How to represent backspace in a string?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Below is the code I am using to restrict user from entering any other characters except for the predefined ones. But using my code I cannot hit backspace.

How to include backspace also ?

```
 Dim s As String = "0123456789$"

 If s.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
   e.Handled = True
 End If
```

Comment: A similar post with a good answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530776/textbox-accept-only-digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a fine list of the **[Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx#Y35)**

```
Keys.Back
```

like:

```
If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then
  .......
End If
```

Comment: @Casper Don't know much about Enumeration can you explain your code a bit. What should come in the dotted area? Are you asking me to add your code to mine or asking me to define it using enumeration. Instead of dots , can you show me how you can restrict the user to entering only a and b (that should be able to give me a clear idea)

Comment: the dotted area represents the code that is executed when the backspace key is NOT pressed ;)

Answer (score 1):

`ControlChars.Back` should give you the backspace character.

Answer (score 1):

as per previous posts:

```
Dim s As String = "0123456789$" & ControlChars.Back

If s.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
  e.Handled = True
End If
```